# Problems in Installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just installed rails on my mac. However when I create a directory for application, I get the following error.

```
:~ shankey$ rails tickets
/Users/shankey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Shankey Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/shankey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/shankey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /Users/shankey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

I am new to rails, excuse me if I am missing something obvious.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: For a helpful tutorial, check out Rails Tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book - That links to the Rails 3.2 version. You can select the 4.0 version there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify if ruby is currently installed, by typing the following command

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
```

you should get similar output. Once, you have verified that ruby is correctly install. then install rails, by folllowing command

```
$ gem install rails
```

this command will take a while, once gem installation completes. you can create new app & try to run the server doing the by following

```
$ rails new demo_app
$ cd demo_app
$ rails server
```

if you have done everything correctly, you should see that famous "riding on rails" welcome page. Lastly, in case you get any errors. Just post again with error message.